# How do I extract the components of a tuple in DAML?

Tags: daml

Given a pair in DAML, e.g. constructed by `(1, "test")`, how can I get the first and second components out?

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you tried? What were you expecting the result to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a DAML pair `x` of type `(Int, Text)`, you can get the first component (`1` in your example) using the selector `x._1` or the `fst` function as `fst x`. You can get the second component (`"test"` in your example) with `x._2` or `snd x`.

The `x._1` selector works on all tuples (pairs, triples and beyond), while `fst` only works on pairs. The function `fst3` (and `snd3`, `thd3`) are available in `DA.Tuple` to work on triples.

Answer (score 1):

For a tuple that has a number of elements, you could use

```
let (a,_,c,_) = someFunction

-- do something to a or c
```