# How are multiple return arguments from a choice accessed

Tags: daml

I have a choice defined as:

```
MyChoice: ( ContractId X, ContractId X )
        ....
        return ( a, b )
```

How do I use `a` or `b` in a scenario as an argument for something else? Dot notation doesn't appear to work.

Comment: This is a duplicate of ["How do I extract the components of a tuple in DAML?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763514/how-do-i-extract-the-components-of-a-tuple-in-daml). It boils down to extracting the components from a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `._1` and `._2` as accessors; or you can use `fst` and `snd` as functions to extract the elements.

You can also bind the components of a pair using pattern matching when the choice is exercised, like so:

```
somecode = do
   (x,y) <- exercise myCid MyChoice with ...
   doStuffWith x
   doStuffWIth y
```